# Appium Wdio not run = ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4723

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium, wdio

Run npx wdio and not run ı more try but ı did not PLease help me this issue always

My caps

```
capabilities: [{
    
    platformName: "Android",
    "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
    "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
    "appium:app": join(process.cwd(), "./app/android/Berqnet Connect 3.1.0-1.apk"),
}],
```

My Bugs

```
ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4723
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
FAILED in Android - C:(MyFiles)\Desktop\wdioDers\test\specs\sample.js
```

My sample.js File

```
describe('Sample', () => {
it('Sample Test', () =>{

});
```

});

Answer (score 3):

Note that the error "ECONNREFUSED ::1:4723" complains about "::1" address which is a loopback address for IPv6.

I've got a similar problem after upgrading to Node 18 (from Node 16) on CircleCI.

In my case, the error looked like this:

> Unable to connect to “http://localhost:4723/”, make sure browser driver is running on that address.
>
> ..
>
> ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4723

The `localhost` resolves to IPv6 address `::1` and the connection fails as the server (Appium) only runs on IPv4 address (`127.0.0.1`).

The problem is caused by the change in Node’s DNS lookup procedure and starting with Node 17, it does not resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1 (IPv4 address) by default (instead it got resolved to IPv6 ::1 address which caused connection error):

> Node.js no longer re-sorts results of IP address lookups and returns them as-is (i.e. it no longer ignores how your OS has been configured)

Discussion is here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702.

In the case of native webdriver.io tests, it both starts the server (Appium) and acts as a client, trying to connect to it via `http://localhost:4723`.

I found a configuration option to change the [port](https://webdriver.io/docs/appium-service/#options), but I didn’t find a way to configure Appium server address (to change
`localhost` to `127.0.0.1`). As a simpler solution, I switched to Node 20 before running tests:

```bash
nvm install 20
nvm use 20
cd e2e-webdriver
npm run test:ios
```

This way tests run with Node 20 that has a fall-back to IPv4 and the connection works.

Comment: confirming that upgrading from node 18 to node 20 solved my issue. This is the weirdest thing ever, because I WAS running tests on node 18 just fine. So I was skeptical node v is the issue

Answer (score 2):

I think you need show full code of "wdio.config.js" to everyone can help you check around your config.
Maybe, You can check the value of "services" in wdio.config.js file. You must set value of services is "**services: ['appium']**"
I hope it will help you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to look for answers to this solution, if you're on windows and use WSL. If the code is run on WSL while using the appium GUI on normal port, you can't connect through so you need to either:

1. Open port connection from WSL to windows port
2. move the code to windows and run it from there

Hope this helps anyone who's having the same issue as I did and couldn't find the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in version node js. For all works, you need to install the latest version recommended for most users(Not the latest Latest Features)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).